# How to fix "Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1" when trying to convert a m3u8 file into a mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg, mp4, m3u8

I'm currently coding a desktop util that downloads Twich Clips if they meet some requirements. As the twitch api gives as a response a m3u8 file, I have to convert it into a mp4. To do with I'm executing a cmd command through my Java application using the ProcessBuilder API built into Java. The command works fine, but sometimes I get a buggy video that has broken frames and audio. Here's my code:

```
public static void convertFile(File input, File output) {
    String command = "ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -vsync 2 -i \"" + input.getAbsolutePath() + "\" -c copy " + "\"" + output.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    System.out.println("______________________________________________________");
    System.out.println("Converting file...");
    System.out.println("Using as input " + input.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Using as output " + output.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Using as command: " + command);
    System.out.println("______________________________________________________");
    setHasDone(false);

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
    pb.command(command.split(" "));

    pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

    Process process;
    try {
        process = pb.start();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    while (process.isAlive()){
        setHasDone(false);
    }

    setHasDone(true);
}
```

Example of broken video:
https://youtu.be/FfFvStNl-9o

When uploaded to youtube lot's of the video bugs are not present, not really know why, but at the end you can clearly see what I'm talking about. Am I using ffmepg wrong?

I posted this as none of the 1000 answers on similar posts helped me.

Comment: Still lookin for help!

Comment: Is your m3u8 a list of media you want to concatenate?

Comment: No, It's a m3u8 file that contains the same video in different res, but the default one(the one that gets converted) is the 720p60fps